# Serverless: Deploy Endpoint with Custom Authorizer - Name Not Found Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless-framework

I am working with the [Serverless](http://www.serverless.com) framework deploying a function with a custom authorizer. The issue is similar to the [one described in this thread](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/1056) , but there is no solution detailed.

Basically, I have a custom authorizer and function set up as spec'd in the documentation, yet when I deploy the function (with endpoint) the error I get is this error:

```
Serverless:   POST - exampleTest: Endpoint exampleTest~POST has an 'authorizerFunction' specified that does not exist in this project.  Make sure the function's 'authorizer' property is filled in
```

Here is my s-function.json portion for the endpoint:

```
  "endpoints": [
{
  "path": "exampleTest",
  "method": "POST",
  "type": "AWS",
  "authorizationType": "custom",
  "authorizerFunction": "exampleAuth",
  "apiKeyRequired": false,
  "requestParameters": {},
  "requestTemplates": "$${apiRequestTemplate}",
  "responses": {
    "400": {
      "statusCode": "400"
    },
    "default": {
      "statusCode": "200",
      "responseParameters": {},
      "responseModels": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": "Empty"
      },
      "responseTemplates": {
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the entire s-function.json for the custom authorizer:

```
    {
  "name": "exampleAuth",
  "runtime": "nodejs4.3",
  "description": "Custom Auth Function for API",
  "customName": false,
  "customRole": false,
  "handler": "handler.handler",
  "timeout": 30,
  "memorySize": 256,
  "authorizer": {},
  "custom": {
    "excludePatterns": []
  },
  "endpoints": [],
  "events": [],
  "environment": {
    "SERVERLESS_PROJECT": "${project}",
    "SERVERLESS_STAGE": "${stage}",
    "SERVERLESS_REGION": "${region}"
  },
  "vpc": {
    "securityGroupIds": [],
    "subnetIds": []
  }
}
```

Not sure if it matters, but the function and the custom authorizer are in the same project but different folders (i.e. the authorizer is not a sub-folder to the function).

Lastly, if I manually add the custom authorizer everything works fine.

Thanks for any help or direction!

**EDIT:**
After additional research I believe the issue is related to the 'authorizer' portion of the s-function.json. This is in the header of the file, not in the endpoint. I don't see a sample of this setting and I'm not sure what to put here. Any ideas or an example would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the error in my s-function.json was due to the 'authorizer' field in the custom authorization function (not in the endpoint or function that implements the auth code).

I needed to add this to the s-function.json:

```
"authorizer": {
        "type": "TOKEN",
        "identitySource": "method.request.header.Authorization",
        "authorizerResultTtlInSeconds": "300"
      },
```

For anyone struggling with the same issue, here is the completed s-function.json for custom authorization.

```
    {
  "name": "exampleAuth",
  "runtime": "nodejs4.3",
  "description": "Custom Auth Function for exampleAPI",
  "customName": false,
  "customRole": false,
  "handler": "handler.handler",
  "timeout": 30,
  "memorySize": 256,
  "authorizer": {
    "type": "TOKEN",
    "identitySource": "method.request.header.Authorization",
    "authorizerResultTtlInSeconds": "300"
  },
  "custom": {
    "excludePatterns": []
  },
  "endpoints": [],
  "events": [],
  "environment": {
    "SERVERLESS_PROJECT": "${project}",
    "SERVERLESS_STAGE": "${stage}",
    "SERVERLESS_REGION": "${region}"
  },
  "vpc": {
    "securityGroupIds": [],
    "subnetIds": []
  }
}
```

I haven't figured out how to add a Token Validation Expression yet, and I understand there is issues with the console reflecting the region and name, but otherwise it works perfect.